What is this GenAI that can generate multiple images with the same person?
I saw a video a few days ago about a new (or maybe just new version of) GenAI that can generate images with the same person over and over again. The newly generated image can contain the same person that it is previously generated but now in a new image and can even have other poses.
I would like to know what is this GenAI called, and how can I access it?


I would like to know what is this GenAI called

This task is sometimes referred to as character consistency eg see this SIGGRAPH 2024 paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.10093

Do you know which GenAI software has the capability to do such task as of now? because that is what my question asks.

@holydragon 1 question per post, better.

I agree, and that is what I intend to do. I didn't ask for the terminology of this task. I asked for the GenAI that can do this task. I still get no answer.

@holydragon Got it, I guess some language misunderstanding, no pb. Which text-to-image service/model can preserve character consistency?

I don't see why it needs to be created as a new question/answer altogether since it is just a reworded question of mine, but you provided the answer I wanted. Thank you.

@holydragon you're welcome! (Question 1: how is it called? Question 2: which service can do it?)
